# exec() rsync command doesn't work with Laravel8

Tags: php, laravel, rsync

Hope someone can shed some light on this one, it's driving me nuts. I have a backup web app written in php, this creates an rsync which is run on a remote server and stores the files in a local folder. This function works using the php exec function.

We are migrating this to within a laravel8 app and the identical call to the same rsync and to the same local storage directory fails. The error is a 255.

If i use the same rsync command from command line it works the same as it does in our original app.

A bit more...
The Laravel instance is using Horizon to perform this so i have this in the handle() function of a process file in the jobs folder.

Of note I have a dev version of this laravel app and with this it works correctly and syncs with the remote folder.

My rsync command is using an id_rsa file for the apache user - www-data (the app is not available to the outside world). the folders have the correct permissions and owners (www-data and 755 for directories and 644 for files).

an example (modified version) of the rsync command:

```
rsync -rLDvcs -e "ssh -p 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa" --no-perms --no-group --no-owner --progress --exclude-from '/var/www/backup/exclude.txt' --delete --backup --backup-dir=/hdd/mnt/incs/deleted_files/the-project/ theproject@188.102.210.41:/home/theproject/files/ /hdd/mnt/incs/theproject/files
```

the code which calls this is:

```
$aResult['res'] = exec($rsync . ' 2>&1', $aResult['output'], $aResult['return']);
```

when run $aResult['return'] has a value of 255 and the process has failed. The docs seem to say this is a failure to connect yet the identical call on another app on the same machine works (as it does if rsync is used in command line)

Any ideas? The php version on this box (the original app and the laravel upgrade) is php8.0 and my dev copy uses php7.4. my dev and this internal box use Ubuntu20.04 and apache2 so besides the php version are pretty identical.

No error is in any logs.

thanks

Craig